# Is there a way to add "bookmark" or "favorite" in WebEx?

Tags: webex, cisco-webex

Can we add a person in WebEx so that we can click and start a meeting with the person?  For example, right now I have to add a bookmark to Google Chrome:

```
https://cisco.webex.com/meet/someUserName
```

and then whenever I use that bookmark on Google Chrome, it will open up a webpage and ask if I want to start WebEx with that person.  Is there a direct way to add the bookmark / favorite to WebEx?

Comment: Mike's answer below works well for Personal Rooms.  It would be nice if there was a way to also add a Meeting Number to the 'Join a Meeting' window (Mike's screenshot).  @McFly's answer below is the only way I've found to do it for Meeting Numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I found yet is - when you join to meeting call via inserting personal page in **Join Meeting** edit field, the application (Cisco Webex Meeting) remembers it. And later, you can use list of *most recent personal rooms* to connect them.

[image]

[(app screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2drC.png)

Answer (score 1):

The only way as of now, is to add bookmarks to your browser (which you are already doing).
I have a separate folder for different meeting rooms added to my firefox browser.